# Spring LDAP core not compatibile with Spring 5?

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap

I'm developing a Java Web Application with Spring 5 (not Spring Boot) and I'm facing a problem with the library spring-ladp-core (2.3.2.RELEASE).

I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:155)
```

and I can't understand exactly what's the problem, maybe a dependencies version problem but I don't know how to solve it. I mean the spring-ldap-core is no more updated since 2017 so is it outdated? Is supposed no longer be used?

I need to build an authentication mechanism with Spring security and LDAP, is the spring-security-ldap library the correct way to implement this?

I have an "old" project with Spring 4 and spring-ldap-core and it works fine, is spring-ldap-core no more compatibile with recent versions of Spring (Spring > 4)?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't related to Spring LDAP. But the fact that you are mixing incompatible versions of jars from Spring itself. Never mix different versions of a framework, that is trouble waiting to happen.

Comment: @M.Deinum ok in order not mixing diferent versions but seems doesn't exists a recent version of spring-ldap-core, I mean a version matching Spring 5.x.y

Comment: It is still used in Spring Security 5.3 which supports Spring 5.2 so it does work. But as stated, it isn't related to Spring LDAP but the mere fact you are mixing jars from different versions of Spring itself.

Comment: @M.Deinum ok I will check but the point is that without the spring-ldap-core lib the application works fine, so I presume there aren't problems related to the Spring libs

Comment: Yes there is. THe Spring Ldap isprobably compiled against another version of Spring. Which is being pulled in (a single jar) which leads to trouble. DO a `mvn dependency:tree` and figure out which one.